# PowerShell Get-ClusterGroup won't allow multiple nodes

Tags: powershell-2.0, cluster-computing

I am trying to come up with a script to verify that cluster resources are online on multiple clusters based on a list. I have the below but Get-Content is not working. I've tried quotes and parenthesis around "Get-Content" but still nothing. If I put just the node names separated by comma's, it works fine.  What am I missing? Also, how can I filter out the "Cluster Group" and Available Storage" in the results? I really only want to know if the resources are online. Thank you.

```
Import-Module FailoverClusters

$clusters = Get-Content -Path C:\clusters.txt
ForEach ($cluster in $clusters)
{
$clusterNodes = Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $cluster  ;
$clusterNodes|select Name,OwnerNode, State|Sort-Object NodeName|Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize;

}
```

------------Results--------------

```
Name              OwnerNode        State
----              ---------        -----
Resource1         Server1         Online
Cluster Group     Server2         Online
Available Storage Server2         Online
Resource2         Server1         Online
Resource3         Server1         Online
Resource4         Server1         Online
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter it out based on the cluster resources property `iscoregroup`

```
get-clustergroup | where iscoregroup -eq $false | select name, ownernode, state |Sort-Object
     NodeName|Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize;
```